# Tcp echo server not responding to external IP addresses

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

I've implemented a simple echo server using [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13232/A-very-basic-TCP-server-written-in-C)

After this, I installed it on a remote computer (aws server, the target port is open in the security group) and tried to connect to it via internet.

The server does not respond (times out).

I've tried adding exception to the firewall or even disabling the firewall on the target computer, without any effect.

I've also tried connecting to the software which runs on the target computer, and that works fine.

What could be the cause of this behavior?

Comment: Telnet the port openend on the remote server from your client to see if the connection can be done. telnet <ipremoteserver> <portremoteserver>

Comment: Have you tried to telnet into the port? try a tool such as http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/ if you are not familiar with telnet... This way you can see exactly if it is connecting or you can also use wireshark to see what is going in and out... http://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server is bound to 127.0.0.1, so it won't accept connections from outside the local host. Bind it to 0.0.0.0 instead.

Comment: I'v changed _listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), _port)) to _listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), _port)), and now it won't accept connections from the localhost

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means "all interfaces"; the listening socket will then accept requests regardless of the interface on which they originate.  If it's not accepting from "localhost", something else is wrong.